# I need a web terminal for running command lines on web page using Chrome

Tags: windows, command-line, node.js, terminal-emulator

Basically I just want to be able to type windows command lines like "cd", "dir", "mkdir" etc directly on a web page (instead of using command prompt). Is that possible at all? Is there a free & ready-to-use software that I can use?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: There is a terminal app in JavaScript, which you can run in your browser. Don't remember the name. Google might help.

Comment: If you want to write the commands yourself then you can use https://terminal.jcubic.pl/